# drupal 8 Calling a JavaScript function after an #AJAX event

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-ajax

I want that js script running after doing the ajax action.

For example, its work for Drupal 7:

```
  Drupal.behaviors.events = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('#example').bind('ajaxSuccess', function(data, status, xhr) {
      >>code here<<
    });
  }
};
```

how to write a successful script for Drupal 8?

Comment: Does your `#ajax` is a callback on a form ? Could you add your Drupal 8 code of your own `#ajax` implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

By using an object `\Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand` on a `\Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse::addCommand()`.

Ajax can be used with forms to provide various things. The typical steps involved:

- Create a form.
- Within a `::buildForm()` use a `#ajax` render element.
- Create the callback.

There are two ways to respond to the ajax request. You may either respond with an `AjaxResponse` object or with HTML to replace the element with which may either be raw HTML or a render array.

**To invoke your own Javascript function - as you want - you have to respond with an `AjaxResponse` object.**

Here is a [complete documentation of Ajax on Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms).

---

Here is the example:

Partial `::buildForm()` with the implementation of Ajax render element:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type'        => 'submit',
  '#value'       => $this->t('Send'),
  '#ajax'        => [
    'callback' => [$this, 'respondToAjax'],
  ]
];
```

Here is the Ajax callback method, in the same form:

```
/**
 * @param array $form
 *   Form API array structure.
 * @param array $form_state
 *   Form state information.
 *
 * @return \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse
 *   Response object.
 */
public function respondToAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#example', 'ajaxSuccess'));
  return $response;
}
```

---

You can find here a [list of all commands you can pass in the response](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21CommandInterface.php/interface/implements/CommandInterface).

Comment: but I do not need to write a php code. I do not need to create a form. I want to just have the JS handler on the run after a successful ajax hang.

And Drupal 7 my example worked. I think Drupal 8 has changed a little bit.

Comment: So it seems your question is misleading. You should add some more information. Example, *which form* or *action* are you trying to "hook" after an Ajax call this is related to a core module or a contrib module ?

Comment: well, the module is from the core. Form for editing the user profile. Add a picture of the user. And I want, that when the picture is loaded (or deleted), this is just an Ajax form. My js code should work.